# Different AIC values in trace and final output in `auto.arima`

Tags: r, arima, aic

I am trying to fit a time series with function `auto.arima` in the "forecast" package in R that is choosing the best model automatically. Since I am using it for my thesis, I have to show the trace of stepwise selection algorithm manually (without adding line "trace" in `auto.arima` code) with my web apps here https://nugraha92.shinyapps.io/Analisis/

But, when I manually checked it, I found that `auto.arima` did not choose minimum AIC values.

Then, I input the `trace=TRUE` line and the result shows that the AIC/BIC value is not the same between the "trace ARIMA list" and "choosen ARIMA model". For example, in the image it is shown that the best model is ARIMA(3,1,3), BIC score at the list is -252.4451 while at the equation below is -250.89.

Why and which one is the correct one? Did I make some mistakes?

[image]

Comment: *But, when I manually checked it, I found that `auto.arima` did not choose minimum AIC values.* Well, you have specified BIC to be the criterion of choice: `ic="bic"`. AIC is not the same as BIC and the choice by the two need not coincide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto.arima` uses an approximation to speed up calculations. The final reported AIC/AICc/BIC values are computed without the approximation. Set `approximation=FALSE` if you want to avoid using the approximation. Then the values produced by `trace=TRUE` will match the final values reported.